# How to pass multiple parameter in jquery onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
var from='2022-02-21';
var to='2022-02-25';
var category ='rt';
var btndiv = '<div class="col-12 text-right">\
               <input type="button" value="Generate Invoice" id="btngenerateinvoice" onclick="generateinvoice('+ from + ',' + to + ',' + category + ')" class="btn btn-blue btn-sm" /></div>';
    $(".btndiv").append(btndiv);
});


function generateinvoice(ff, tt, cc) {
    alert("helo");
    var f = ff;
    var t = tt;
    var c = cc
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row btndiv">
                                
</div>
```

I pass three-parameter on onclick generateinvoice function dynamically but generateinvoice these function not called

Comment: what exactly does not work?

Comment: Can you explain in a little brief? Exactly where you are trying to add parameters?

Comment: Are the values of the variables different every time you click a button?

Comment: i am trying pass parameter in onclick

Comment: yes it will different every time @Andy

Comment: function generateinvoice(ff, tt, cc) {
    alert("helo");
    var f = ff;
    var t = tt;
    var c = cc
    
} this function is not called when i click the function

Comment: @RanjithRaina Do you get the alert? or what is not working?

Comment: No these function not called alert also not working @CarstenLøvboAndersen

Comment: @RanjithRaina Please edit your question, use the snippet tool `<>` to make a working example of the problem

Comment: @RanjithRaina Also hit F12 and see if there is any errors in the console

Comment: OK, so the part of the code that's missing that's getting us confused is that you're using a loop (I guess) to iterate over an array of objects? @RanjithRaina

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the values inside `onclick="generateinvoice` when they are rendered, the code thinks it's variables and those have not been defined. You can add `\'` in front and after each variable.

so you can do `onclick="generateinvoice(\''+ from + '\',\'' + to + '\',\'' + category + '\')"`

Without the `\'` the rendered code could look like `generateinvoice(from,to,category)`, but when you add those the code will render the variables as string,s so it looks like `generateinvoice('from','to','category')`

**Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var from = "f",
    to = "t",
    category = "cc";

  var btndiv = '<div class="col-12 text-right">\
               <input type="button" value="Generate Invoice" id="btngenerateinvoice" onclick="generateinvoice(\''+ from + '\',\'' + to + '\',\'' + category + '\')" class="btn btn-blue btn-sm" /></div>';
  $(".btndiv").append(btndiv);
});


function generateinvoice(ff, tt, cc) {
  alert("helo");
  var f = ff;
  var t = tt;
  var c = cc

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row btndiv">

</div>
```

Comment: thank you @carsten lovbo its working now  kindly explain if i add    '/ ' in front of varaible what that means ?

Comment: @RanjithRaina added more to the answer